# Grub doesn't load after dual booting

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

I had Windows 10 installed on my laptop,and recently dual booted with Ubuntu 16.04,but after successful installation,the OS selection menu does not appear and directly boots up Windows. If I go to BIOS ,and enter Boot Device Options and select Ubuntu,then it works perfectly fine.I have also tried ,boot-repair but did not help.Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: See this https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: After the first command "sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair" it shows "gpg key-server communications error:unknown pubkey algorithm".

Answer (score 0):

A useful software is [easybcd](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). It allows  to  add, remove boot entries, configure the boot menu: superhelpful. try it.